# VB.NET Send keys to other application with focusing on it

Tags: vb.net, sendkeys

I want to send keys to other application with focusing on it with VB.NET. I want to be able to send a Keydown message and a KeyUp message. But without focusing on the application I want to send keys to.

The following example focuses on the application when it is sending the keys. I don't want that.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18366/Sending-Keystrokes-to-another-Application-in-C

The reason for this is I want to be able to Login with 2 games/windows onto 1 server and play with both of them. I have macros keys so I can set them to run this code. which will for example move the character on the 2nd game window while I control the character on my 1st game window. Like send "W" to move the 2nd character forward.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

In a quick research (I bet you dit it as well), I haven't found it possible.
SendKey is a way to simulate inputs at OS level, and not application level.

**A *possible* workaround**

That said, one way you could accomplish that would be creating a Virtual Machine and then run your automation script on it, keeping the host OS free. I'm just affraid that depending of the resources required by the game your are running (3D renderization), the VM specs maybe won't fit.

(Since I hate answers as "you can't do that", I just found interesting to share this palliative)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, creating a virtual machine seems a like it would create more problems than it would solve. I was just hoping there was an API for it. Like SetText.